# How can I reverse each word in a string and the first letter is capitalized of each word in Python?

Tags: python, string

How can I reverse each word in a string and the first letter is capitalized of each word in Python?

```
input = 'this is the best'
output = Siht Si Eht Tseb
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), then reverse the string and finally [`capitalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize):

```
s = 'this is the best'

res = " ".join([si[::-1].capitalize() for si in s.split()])
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
Siht Si Eht Tseb
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
" ".join([str(i[::-1]).title() for i in input.split()])
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here works as well. But I think this will be a lot easier to understand.

```
s = 'this is the best'

words = s.split()  # Split into list of each word
res = ''
for word in words:
    word = word[::-1]  # Reverse the word
    word = word.capitalize() + ' '  # Capitalize and add empty space
    res += word  # Append the word to the output string

print(res)
```